# function to unzip a tuple into two lists Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a function that takes a list of tuples `[(a,b)]` and unzips it into `[a]` and `[b]`. I've had a look on Hoogle but the only function I can find is `unzip` but that takes a tuple and returns a list within a tuple. Is there a function that can do this? If not, would it be appropriate to use `unzip` and then create a function that returns the first list for `[a]` and the second list for `[b]`.

Comment: What do you imagine the type of your function would be?

Comment: `unzip` is exactly what you need. Can you clarify why you think it's not suitable? With don't pseudocode perhaps?

Comment: You write _a function that returns the first list for `[a]` and the second list for `[b]`_. Well, `unzip` does just that, returning the two lists together, in a pair. How would you expect to get the two lists, if not in a pair? I think you _think_ you need something other than `unzip`, but you don't. Maybe giving a clue about the overall goal you're trying to reach would help us help you.

Comment: @Enlico *"How ... to get the two lists, if not in a pair?"* `foo xs k = let {(a,b) = unzip xs} in k a b`.

Comment: @WillNess, aren't you still using `(a,b) = unzip xs`, where the two lists are in a pair?

Comment: @Enlico it was just a gist of an illustration. see Jon's answer for more. :)

Answer (score 2):

`unzip :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])` does return both lists `[a]` and `[b]`, they’re just wrapped in a pair because all Haskell function types have exactly one input and one output.

In order to extract the result, you can use pattern-matching with `case`:

```
-- | Example input.
input :: [(Int, Char)]
input = [(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D')]
```

```
main = case unzip input of
  (fs, ss) -> do
    print fs   -- [1,2,3,4]
    print ss  -- "ABCD"
```

Or, because this pattern is complete (irrefutable, ignoring nontermination), with a `let` or `where` binding:

```
main = do
  let
    (fs, ss) = unzip input
  print fs
  print ss
```

```
main = do
  print fs
  print ss
  where
    (fs, ss) = unzip input
```

If you *only* want the list of firsts or the list of seconds, you can extract them separately:

```
main = do

  let fs = map fst input
  print fs

  let ss = map snd input
  print ss
```

```
firsts :: [(a, b)] -> [a]
firsts = map fst

seconds :: [(a, b)] -> [b]
seconds = map snd

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let
    fs = firsts input
    ss = seconds input
  print fs
  print ss
```

However, if you’re going to use both `map fst` and `map snd`, this traverses the input list twice, so `unzip` is preferable, because it only traverses a single time.

Using a tuple is the normal way of returning multiple results from a function, when there are only a few (2–3). If there are more than that, then a record type is preferable, so that the fields can be given clear names.

Another way of returning multiple results is *continuation-passing style* (CPS), which in this context just means passing both results to a user-specified “callback” function instead of returning them in a tuple:

```
unzipCps
  :: [(a, b)]           -- ^ Input list
  -> ([a] -> [b] -> c)  -- ^ Output callback
  -> c

unzipCps ((x, y) : rest) returnBoth
  = unzipCps rest prependBoth
  where
    prependBoth xs ys = returnBoth (x : xs) (y : ys)

unzipCps [] returnBoth = returnBoth [] []

main = do

  -- Equivalent to the original ‘unzip’.
  let (fs, ss) = unzipCps input (,)
  print fs
  print ss

  -- The result type (‘c’ in ‘unzipCps’)
  -- can be anything, including an ‘IO’ action.
  unzipCps input $ \ fs ss -> do
    print fs
    print ss
```

Sometimes this style is necessary when using `GADTs`/`RankNTypes`, or helpful for implementing performance optimisations, however in this case there’s no particular advantage to using it, and it has different performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

You write *a function that returns the first list for `[a]` and the second list for `[b]`*. Well, `unzip` does just that, returning the two lists together, in a pair. Returning a pair is the most straightforward way of returning two things in Haskell.

I think you *think* you need something other than `unzip`, but you don't. For instance, let's say you have a `[(Int,String)]` and all you want to do is to multiply all the `Int`s obtaining `n`, concatenate the the `String`s obtaining `s`, and then returning `s ++ " = " ++ show n`. You could do so:

```hs
input = [(1,"x"),(2,"y"),(3,"z")]
output = let (nums, strings) = unzip input -- nums and strings are the two lists
             n = product nums
             s = concat strings
         in s ++ " = " ++ show n
```